# Проблема с firebase listadapter

Tags: android, firebase

Ребята, вроде бы всё делаю правильно, но почему-то ошибку выбивает.
Мне нужно,чтобы вывело список, в котором будут находится все профили.

```
public class ListProfiles extends Fragment {
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    ListView listView;
    private static final String TAG = "List";
    FirebaseListAdapter<ProfileUserInfo> myAdapter;
    public ListProfiles() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_profiles, container, false);
        listView=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_prof);

        list();
        return v;
    }

    public void list(){
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("profiles").;
        myAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ProfileUserInfo>(getActivity(),ProfileUserInfo.class,R.layout.list_profiles,
                myRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View view, ProfileUserInfo model, int position) {
                Log.i(TAG,model.getName().toString());
                TextView name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_name);
                TextView email=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_email);
                TextView phone=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_phone);
                name.setText(model.getName());
                email.setText(model.getEmail());
                phone.setText(model.getPhone());
            }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

}
```

ProfileUserInfo:

```
package by.ittech.test_chat.Profile;


public class ProfileUserInfo {
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;



    public ProfileUserInfo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public ProfileUserInfo(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public ProfileUserInfo(String name, String phone, String email) {

        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public ProfileUserInfo() {

    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибки:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: by.ittech.test_chat, PID: 6976
                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at by.ittech.test_chat.ListProfiles.ListProfiles$1.populateView(ListProfiles.java:55)
                                                                       at by.ittech.test_chat.ListProfiles.ListProfiles$1.populateView(ListProfiles.java:48)
                                                                       at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.getView(FirebaseListAdapter.java:149)
                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:927)
                                                                       at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:966)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:73
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё,сделал. Просто перепутал layouts